# VB.Net Process selection for chrome if flash is open

Tags: vb.net

still stuck on why this is producing 0 and not picking up that flash is open in the browser if anyone can help ill put the code below thank you oh and along with the dll. I have imported it i have done everything to my knowledge thanks

```
Public Browser As Browser = New Browser()
Public AOB As AOB = New AOB()
Public processid As IntPtr
Private browsername As String = "NA"
Dim sc3n As New FacilCoding

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.None, ExactSpelling:=False)>
Public Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean
End Function
Public Sub selectbrowser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles selectbrowser.Click


    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Chrome" Then

        processid = Browser.Chrome()
        MsgBox(processid.ToString)
        browsername = "Chrome"

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Edge" Then
        processid = Browser.Edge_Flash()
        browsername = "Edge"
    End If
    If processid = 0 Then
        lblpidbrowser.Text = "Failed to Attach to " + browsername
        AOB.processhandle = IntPtr.Zero
    Else
        AOB.OpenProcessid(processid)
        lblpidbrowser.Text = "Attached To " + browsername + "PID : " + processid + " / " + processid.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

[DLL Where the browser code is ect](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bjAvoclSL_YRNttUKj_0IE9KweLbKJWP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the dll was a little bit messed up from using obfuscation so i know have the original and it is working fine now it picks up every browser !